# CMake Errors whilst building Catkin (Raspbian)

Tags: ros, catkin, raspberrypi, cmake, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone

Really sorry if this is something silly or small I've gotten wrong, or if it's something that has been answered somewhere else on here. I am having issues getting through compiling on my raspberry pi. Below I have the last few lines that seem relevant before it stopped running. I also need to point out that I'm new to this. Am studying robotics at university and have followed the ROS Platform forever but only recently started trying to learn how to use it.

```
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/pi/build_isolated/orocos_kdl/test_results
-- catkin 0.5.65
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.26")
-- checking for module 'eigen3'
--   package 'eigen3' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 

(MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Eigen (missing: EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:288 
(_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/eigen/cmake/eigen-config.cmake:31 
(find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 658, in 
build_workspace_isolated
    number=index + 1, of=len(ordered_packages)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 443, in build_package
    install, jobs, force_cmake, quiet, last_env, cmake_args, make_args
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 278, in 
build_catkin_package
    os.remove(makefile)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'/home/pi/build_isolated/orocos_kdl/Makefile'
<== Failed to process package 'orocos_kdl':
  [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/build_isolated/orocos_kdl/Makefile'
Command failed, exiting.
```

Again, really sorry if this is something silly or small I've gotten wrong. Thank you in advance for any help you can give!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60907/cmake-errors-whilst-building-catkin-(raspbian)/) by [Chloegeek](https://answers.ros.org/users/4699/chloegeek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The CMake error says that [eigen3](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) is not being found in your system. The most likely explanation for this is that eigen simply isn't installed.

Fortunately raspbian does have a native eigen3 package which you can easily install with the command below (answer yes to any questions apt-get asks).

```
sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev
```

However, the [official ROS instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source) for the raspberry pi do not list eigen as a dependency. It could be that there's an error in the documentation, but it could also be that you're not following them correctly :)

---

Originally posted by [Miguel S.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3547/miguel-s./) with karma: 1114 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chloegeek](https://answers.ros.org/users/4699/chloegeek/) on 2013-04-17**:
I was following it all word for word, it does warn against a full desktop install and that's what I was going for, so that could be it. But the warning seemed to be more a case of I can do it but it will be buggy.

**Comment by [Chloegeek](https://answers.ros.org/users/4699/chloegeek/) on 2013-04-17**:
Okay, I have installed as you suggested, going to try run the CMake again now, will come back with the results when I know if it's working or not.